# Grid Layout in QTreeView

Tags: python, qt, view, pyside

Essentially what I want is something like:

```
Parent  
   |---Item--Item--Item
   |---Item--Item--Item
   |---Item--Item
Parent
   |---Item--Item--Item
Parent
   |---Item--Item--Item
   |---Item--Item
```

Instead of the default implementation which is like:

```
Parent  
   |---Item
   |---Item
   |---Item
   |---Item
   |---Item
Parent
   |---Item
   |---Item
Parent
   |---Item
   |---Item
   |---Item
```

I know I can subclass QAbstractItemView and set this up from scratch, but I feel like there is an easier way of doing this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I you are working with models you should subclass QTreeView or QAbstractItemView.

Comment: Sub-classing QAbstractItemView would be my final option.

Comment: To me the difference is in the number of columns in the first and second tree views you shown. If you avoid using models, you can construct a multicolumn QTreeWidget.

Comment: Subclassing the view will get you nowhere. All you need to do is use a [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html), which already supports multiple columns.

Comment: Doing that would mean items would always be in the same column and the number of columns would always be the same correct? I feel like determining the arrangement of the items in the model is the wrong way of doings things. What I want is n-columns based on the available viewport width. I'm probably just going to try and subclass QTreeView if I can try and override the appropriate methods or if that doesn't work I'll write my own view by sub-classing QAbstractItemView.

Comment: @StephenLam. My comment was based on the first layout in your question, which is just a standard multi-column tree-view.